# C pointer + free: Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

Tags: c

I have written the following code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main (int argc , char *argv[])  {
int * ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); 
int three = 3; 
ptr = &three; 
free(ptr);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I execute I get following error:

```
Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT).
```

Could you help me find my mistake?
Thank you!

Comment: `int * ptr = malloc(...); ptr = &three;` is like doing `int x = 10; x = 5;` and then wondering why `x` is not equal to `10`. With a little [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) you should have (hopefully) been able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: You're doing the equivalent of `free(&three)`, which you're not allowed to do.

Comment: Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 4):

What you have is undefined behavior. The C11 standard states thus:

> **7.22.3.3 The free function**
>   ...
>   2 The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, **if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function**, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, **the
>   behavior is undefined.**

In your example the argument of `free` is `&three` which is not a pointer returned by a memory management function and therefore you have the behavior you see.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `malloc` a pointer to memory chunk of requested size is returned (on success). This memory chunk is allocated form heap, and you can use that pointer to un-allocate it by calling `free` later.
Local variables are allocated memory from stack.
What you are doing here is allocating a memory chunk from heap:

```
int * ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and then overwriting then overwriting `ptr` with address of a local variable who's memory resides on stack.

```
ptr = &three;
```

and then attempting to free that memory:

```
free(ptr);
```

which is undefined behaviour.